# Use Regex to get content of a html tag depending on a substring

Tags: regex

Is it possible to select an HTML tag (not-specified) and its contents, depending on whether or not there is a specific string inside it?

e.g.:

```
<tagouter>
    <tag> lorem ipsum youtube lorem ipsum</tag> 
    outer text 
    <tag> lorem ipsum youtube lorem ipsum TEXT 2</tag> 
<tagouter>
```

**Expected result:**

```
array(array('youtube','<tag> lorem ipsum youtube lorem ipsum</tag>'),array('youtube',<tag> lorem ipsum youtube lorem ipsum TEXT 2</tag>))
```

With `/(\byoutube\b)/` it will be possible to get the string itself.
But how to get the containing tags content?

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions to get content from HTML is not a good idea.  See this post:

[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Use an HTML parser instead.